# Kubernetes certificate with Letsencrypt

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to create a certificate with letsencrypt.

When I run the this yml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: grafana-tls
  namespace: grafana
type: "kubernetes.io/tls"
spec:
  secretName: grafana-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  dnsNames:
     - mydomain.com
```

with `kubectl apply -f .\grafana-tls.yml --validate=false`

I encountered with the following error

> Referenced "Issuer" not found: issuer.cert-manager.io "letsencrypt-prod" not found

But when I executed `kubectl get clusterissuer`
I encountered with this result

> NAME                  READY      AGE

> letsencrypt-prod      True       3d22h

To deploy the cluster issuer, I used this config

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: myEmail
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [github](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/discussions/3066) documentation try adding **kind: <ClusterIssuer | Issuer >** under issueref and make sure that clusterissuer and the certificate are getting created in the same namespace.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
Metadata:
  name: grafana-tls
  namespace: grafana
type: "kubernetes.io/tls" 
spec: 
  secretName: grafana-tls
  issuerRef: 
    name: letsencrypt-prod 
    kind: <ClusterIssuer | Issuer > 
dnsNames: 
   - mydomain.com
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097) similar issue for more information.